# PostgreSQL Security Question Remote Connection

Tags: postgresql, security, networking, connection

I was succesfull with connecting another computer with my local PostgreSQL Server(On Windows 10). I've
added two specific lines of arguments in the respectful config files.

postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

pg_hba.conf:

```
host all all all md5
```

I understood, that this connection is now possible in my local Network, where I am currently connected to. Is this really the case, or do I have to look out for some connections outside my network to block them? (ssl = off, hope that without ssl it is only local)

For completness, i also added a firewall rule where I allowed TCP connections for a port [Port] and profiles in a domain, private and public network.

Comment: Your pg_hba will let anyone (with the right username and password) in from anywhere.  You might have a firewall that will block them, but that is not something we can see from the info provided.

Comment: "ssl = off, hope that without ssl it is only local"  This doesn't make much sense.  SSL (without client cert) is to protect the client, not the server.  The bad guys will happily connect over SSL if that is what it takes to hack you.

Comment: So in this sense if I gave you my IPv4 Adresse and Port and so forth, you would be able to connect to my DB from your Computer? Is there a way to restrict that behavior only to Computer in the same network?

Comment: You can specify the IP address range which is allowed to connect as Frank N Stein says, but this would probably be best addressed on the firewall by your network administrator.

Comment: Ok thank you, I try to look into the firewall then, because i do not exactly know which IP adresses i need to Accept, only that they are in the same network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the IP range adding a mask like, I'm not sure about that 3rd "all":

`host all all 192.168.0.1/24 md5`

In any case, you can check the log and see if pg up and listen (pg_log or -l parameter)

Comment: I am aware, that I can limit the ip addresses, but later on i don't who exactly is gonna connect to the database. The only thing I would like to have that they are in the same network as the server. I am only comcerned, if I without it knowing have a connection to the Internet with the Database.

Comment: oh! ok, run a ipconfig to determine your IP address, run psql -h the.up.add.ress -U postgres.run the same command from other machine (install psql) to determinate if you have connectivity-